# Am I right with select of base resistor?

Tags: mosfet, npn, pnp

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f4acEI.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

I did add the NPN 2N3904 because I want to put on sleep the Arduino. So I need to put LOW the GPIO when goes in sleep.

This is a prototype. I will port on an Arduino Mini 3V3.

I did forget the pullup from gate, but cannot edit the schema :(

Load is 5V display, with MAX current usage of 67mA. So per OHM Law, I got ~75 Ohm.

Arduino is 5V and his GPIO drive ON/OFF the 2N3904.

I did study that it is common to assume that base current is 1/10 of the collector current. But, what the collector current in my case? That 67mA?

If yes, I need to select a resistor for

5V (Arduino) - 0.9 (Vbe per datasheet) = 4.1/ (0.067 /10 ) = ~600 ohm?

For R2, Do I need to do same absumption?

Comment: This isn't going to work without a pull-up resistor on the mosfet gate. You also don't need R2

Comment: I did forget the Pull up... But cannot anymore edit the schema. But... Is it my calculation right?

Comment: You need a connection between V1 ground and the Arduino ground.

Answer (score 2):

Your circuit has some problems, particularly that there is nothing pulling the gate of the FET high when the transistor is off.

However, you don't need Q1 at all.  If M1 is indeed a P channel FET that can work well enough with 5 V base drive (I didn't look it up, but that's how you are trying to use it), then just control it directly from the 0 to 5 V digital output.  Driving the digital output low turns on the FET, which powers the load.  Driving the digital output high turns off the FET, which removes power from the load.  Yes, it's that simple.

### Added

> I want to put on sleep the Arduino. So I need to put LOW the GPIO when goes in sleep.

No, you don't.  Any competent microcontroller can set it's pins high, low, or sometimes to high impedance when sleeping.  Pin state can't be changed during sleep, but the polarity is arbitrary.

A single P channel FET that works with 5 V gate drive is still all you need.

### Added 2

> Atmega328 sleeps, if pins are HIGH his comsumption is bigger than they are LOW.

I'm not familiar with the Atmega series, but this doesn't sound right.  Unless you can show me the datasheet snippet where this is stated, I simply don't believe you and conclude that you misunderstood something.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Yes, I did forget the pullup but cannot edit the schema without be a membership :( By the way I did edit the question: I need to put on sleep the Arduino and put pin LOW... for this I got also the NPN. And for resistor calculation? Am I right?

Comment: When an Atmega328 sleeps, if pins are HIGH his comsumption is bigger than they are LOW. Btw, Olin, I would say thank you for your big competence, but, could you answer for my main question? :) How I need select the base resistors? I found that transistor/mosftet electronic section is the most difficult to learn... :)

Comment: @sin: You keep missing the point that there should be no additional transistor, and therefore no base resistor in the first place.  What color should my shirt be if I'm never going to wear it?

Comment: You can check from Gammon website: https://www.gammon.com.au/power , Testing in SLEEP_MODE_PWR_DOWN:


All pins as outputs, and LOW: 0.35 µA (same as before).

All pins as outputs, and HIGH: 1.86 µA.

All pins as inputs, and LOW (in other words, internal pull-ups disabled): 0.35 µA (same as before).

All pins as inputs, and HIGH (in other words, internal pull-ups enabled): 1.25 µA.

Answer (score 0):

If you understand the purpose of each component then the values can be easily calculated. If the FETs were conducting several Amps  at high f, then the gate current would increase. This is due to the inherent rise of gate and input capacitance. Therefore it is common to have a source resistance of driver and series R to match the gate  resistance. In your milliamp range this is not required and so no series gate resister needed, except Shunt turn off resistor (up) to hold it in the off state during power up Reset.

If you required an NPN switch transistor , the base resister would be 10 to 20 times the load resistance (for same current ratio Ic/Ib) which in this case might be your pull-up resistor say 10 K so <200K would work. 
This is to satisfy the BJT’s spec for Vce(sat)

However as already pointed out your sleep mode can drive the gate active high or high Z without the need for an inverter. The difference in sleep current in picoamps should be small.

For Arduino sleep mode , the condition to avoid  is leaving “inputs” floating , especially near half of the supply voltage. This will cause Excessive sleep current if the input and internal output are also at Vcc/2 where CMOS N and P channels will both be conducting   ?? mA.